# C# Assigning mutiple references in one line in if statement

Tags: c#, performance, coding-style, code-readability

I've seen code where the developer assigns properties or local variables from an if statement after performing some method call.

Example:

```
    void SomeMethod() 
    {
       MyObject myObject;

       if ((myObject = DoSomething()) != null)
       {
          //Do some business logic
       }
    }
```

I think it gets very messy when a lot of these assignments are happening, or there is more going on in the if-statement, such as accessing an array.

I personally prefer something like this:

```
    void SomeMethod() 
    {
       MyObject myObject = DoSomething();

       if (myObject != null)
       {
          //Do some business logic
       }
    }
```

Is there any benefit of the first piece of code over the second example? Any miniscule efficiency gains or anything? I want to know if I'm missing something.

A large piece of the code set is becoming nested with this style of code which I **believe** is less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no performance implications to this change - it is a matter of personal preference. This works because an assignment is a value-producing expression, which can be used in comparison or other expressions. The idea is to "fold" the assignment into the header of a conditional, essentially saving a line of code.

Although this makes no difference with a single `if` (the number of lines does not change) it does make a difference for longer chains of conditionals. It is also useful in loops, for example

```
int ch;
while ((ch = reader.Read()) != -1) {
    // Do something with ch
}
```

Comment: There are lots of cool applications of this (I did a 1-line shuffle with an assignment in a closed while loop)! It does reduce readability though, use with care!